# Win 10 Acrylic for non UWP-Apps

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio

Is there already a solution for Acrylic design for non Win 10 Apps? I want to adapt the transparent panel design in a non UWP app.

I know there are already some working prototypes which are not using the Win 10 API, but I would like to use the API instead of doing some silly background screenshotting

Comment: Won't regular `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` or `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` work? This "Acrylic" thing seem to be the same as "Aero" background just with a slightly different shader.

Comment: DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow and also SetWindowCompositionAttribute are both not applying the same effect. So there must be some kind of either attribute or API function to archive this. The UWP acrylic effect adds, as you've said, a lot of additional shaders. So there must be something easier to use than applying those manually to the blurred window :(